# PHP or JavaScript open source code of basic Genetic Algorithm

Tags: php, javascript, generics

I'm searching PHP or JavaScript open source code of basic Genetic Algorithm (or any other evolutionary algorithm). Google has provided C++ and Java libraries. But I'm sure that PHP and JavaScript analogues should also exist due to high popularity of this algorithm. So, I appreciate any useful web-link.

Comment: I doubt that PHP or JavaScript would be a good choice for such heavy algorithms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure but i found some good example try it.

**Example 1:-**

**A "Hello World!" Genetic Algorithm Example in PHP**

This is a hello world example genetic algorithm example written in php. You can use the same algorithm to build useful applications.

See below url:-

http://www.bekirdag.com/tr/php_mysql/a_hello_world_genetic_algorithm_example_in_php.html

**Example 2:-**

**Genetic Algorithm Traveling Salesperson PHP**

see below URL:-

http://thomashunter.name/blog/genetic-algorithm-traveling-salesperson-php/

Comment: First link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used this class (http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2567-PHP-Generic-genetic-algorithms-base-implementation.html) in an old project. With a little tweaking you can achieve a lot of genetic algorithm operations easily.

**Note:** you need to be registered to download the files.

Comment: this site needs to be fixed